# Pandas df groupby and apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'col 1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'col 2': ['c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2'],
    'col 3': ['c3', 'd3', 'e3', 'f3', 'g3'],
    'col 4': ['c4', 'd4', 'e4', 'f4', 'g4'],
    }
    )
```

Desired output is:

```
col 1  col 2  col 3
A      c2;d2  c3;d3
B      e2;f2  e3;f3
C      g2     g3
```

I've succeeded in doing this in the following way:

```
df = df.groupby('col 1').transform( lambda x: ';'.join(x)).drop_duplicates()
```

The problem is that this method does not keep column 1 which i really need. and i couldn't get `apply` working.  I've tried like this but it doesn't seem to work after .`groupby`.

```
apply(lambda x: '*'.join(x.dropna().values.tolist()), axis=1)
```

Comment: You're passing your DF a `dict` with `col 3` repeated twice as a key - the DF is only going to see the last occurence of that...

Comment: this is a nice fix, didnt think of it but the solution posted by jezrael is simple and does what i need. thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can specify columns in list after `groupby` with function [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), `lambda function` is not necessary:

```
df1 = df.groupby('col 1')['col 2','col 3'].agg(';'.join).reset_index()
#alternative
#df1 = df.groupby('col 1', as_index=False)['col 2','col 3'].agg(';'.join)
print (df1)
  col 1  col 2  col 3
0     A  c2;d2  c3;d3
1     B  e2;f2  e3;f3
2     C     g2     g3
```

If want also remove missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'col 1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'col 2': [np.nan, 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2'],
    'col 3': ['c3', 'd3', 'e3', 'f3', 'g3'],
    'col 4': ['c4', 'd4', 'e4', 'f4', 'g4'],
    }
    )
print (df)
  col 1 col 2 col 3 col 4
0     A   NaN    c3    c4
1     A    d2    d3    d4
2     B    e2    e3    e4
3     B    f2    f3    f4
4     C    g2    g3    g4

df1 = (df.groupby('col 1', as_index=False)['col 2','col 3']
         .agg(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna())))
print (df1)
  col 1  col 2  col 3
0     A     d2  c3;d3
1     B  e2;f2  e3;f3
2     C     g2     g3
```

Answer (score 4):

Group on `col 1` (specifying index as false so that it remains a column).  Apply a lambda to each group where you join the values of each group with a semi-colon. Then sort the result in the desired column order (e.g. col 1-3).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'col 1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
     'col 2': ['c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2'],
     'col 3': ['c3', 'd3', 'e3', 'f3', 'g3'],
     'col 4': ['c4', 'd4', 'e4', 'f4', 'g4']})

>>> df.groupby('col 1', as_index=False).agg(
        {'col 2': lambda x: ';'.join(x),
         'col 3': lambda x: ';'.join(x)})[['col 1', 'col 2', 'col 3']]
  col 1  col 2  col 3
0     A  c2;d2  c3;d3
1     B  e2;f2  e3;f3
2     C     g2     g3
```

Comment: i think it solves my problem but the solution posted by jezrael seems simpler. Don't know which performs faster tho. Thank you!